# how to store the up to date images in nodejs having mongoose db

Tags: node.js, mongoose

can you explain me what techniques should I use to store the up to date images? Basically, my purpose is to show almost tem recent updated images for my website. The problem is I dont know how to store the latest images in the mongoose db.

Answer (score 1):

I stored the up to date images by using sort of mongoose.

```
image.find({reviewed:true },null,{sort:{"submittedDate":-1}}, function (err, images){}
```